# How to use paging SharePoint lists along with sorting and filtering

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, splistitem, sorting, paging

I am trying to apply paging in a SharePoint list. Everything works fine with the following query:

```
const queryUrl = `${context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}`
        + `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?`
        + `%24skiptoken=Paged%3DTRUE`
        + ((pageNumber > 1)
          ? `%26p_ID%3D${(pageNumber-1)*pageSize}`
          : ``)
        + `&%24top=${pageSize}`
```

The problem is I want to apply filtering and sorting on fields in the list. In this case, I want to apply paging based on `SequenceNumber` field rather than ID.

I tried using `p_SequenceNumber` in query but it didn't work. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
 const queryUrl = `${context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}`
        + `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?`        /
        /+ `$filter=Enabled eq 1&`
         + `%24skiptoken=Paged%3DTRUE`
        + ((pageNumber > 1)
          ? `%26p_SequenceNumber%3D${sequenceNumberToSkip}` //Doesn't work
          : ``)
        + `&%24top=${pageSize}`
        +`&$orderby= SequenceNumber asc`
        ;
        ;
```